# How can I create a CSSprite class, that makes use of the CCSpriteFrameCache & CCSpriteBatchNode objects?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I have a game that I'm creating that will instantiate a certain type of sprite numerous times.  This sprite will have a simple, looping animation, therefore, I assume I will need to make use of `CCSpriteFrameCache` and `CCSPriteBatchNode` to cache the associated sprite images used for driving the animation process.

I've been reading through the often referenced [How To Use Animations and Sprite Sheets in Cocos2D](http://www.raywenderlich.com/1271/how-to-use-animations-and-sprite-sheets-in-cocos2d) on Raywenderlich.com and I mostly understand the process.

My problem is that he's contained the entire animation sequence within the code of his scene file.  I am having trouble interpreting how put this same code within a child, `CCSprite` class (or similar class) that I've created and using this self-contained sprite within my game scene.

In other words, my desire is to have a `CCSprite` child class that can be instantiated within a scene implementation.  A few parameters are passed into the constructor of the child `CCSprite` and when the sprite is added to the game scene, the animation of the sprite happens automatically and apart from any scene code.

How can I do this?

**Point of (Un-)clarification OR Why I'm getting confused**

In Step #2 of Ray's tutorial, he instructs to add the `CCSpriteBatchNode` that is used for his animated sprite as a child of `self` (which is the game scene.)  If I've defined a `CCSpriteBatchNode` within a `CCSprite` child class implementation, do I need to add the `CCSpriteBatchNode` to my parent scene?  How should I (correctly) do this?

Also, if `CCSpriteFrameCache` is a singleton class, will it cause me any trouble to add `[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] addSpriteFramesWithFile:@"my_sprite.plist"];` in my `CCSprite` constructor, or should I only call this once, say, in the initialization of my application?

In general, I'm just confused.  How can I create a self-contained, animated sprite that I can add (multiple times) to a scene, and my scene not have to worry about wiring up the animation sequence, nor will I bog down the little iOS processor?

I don't really care how I solve this problem.  Maybe I've made a few grand assumptions that are just incorrect.  I'm willing to take a different route in solving this problem, so long as the end result is as outlined above.

Thank you!

Comment: I think you should do all what you're doing inside your layer class instead of doing it inside the sprite.

Comment: Agree, your main confusion comes from the assumption that you have to create a subclass of CCSprite. Also this wouldn't change how you use the batch node, it would still be added to the scene/layer and each of your custom sprites added to it once. Animating the sprite is completely decoupled from sprite batching as long as all the sprite's animation frames are in the same texture (which is simply good practice).

Comment: So, what you're telling me is that I have no choice-- I have to manage the animation from my Scene (i.e. layer)?!  I was hoping this wouldn't be the case, but I kind of understand. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, the resulting sprite should be a child of the batch node (not the reverse). A Batch node is just a widget used to 'batch' the draw calls into a single call : the requiremetn is that all its children - in you case, the animated sprites - stem from the same texture as the batch node. The only reason you would have to use a batch node is that you plan to have many animations from the same texture - animations are not related to batch nodes per se.

so, in your scene :

- create the batch node
- add the batch node as child to the scene.
- create each sprite you want to add.

  - You could extend CCSprite to have the animation created in the ctor.
  - If you want your animations to cleanup after themselves, use a CCSequence (as i show below). In your case, the sprite could be sprite 1 of an animaion, and one of the actions would be a CCAnimate action.
- add them to the batch node.

sequence :

```
CCSprite *icn = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@_enabled.png", sk.skillIconPrefix]];
[icn setBlendFunc:(ccBlendFunc) {GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE}];

icn.opacity = 0;
id fadein = [CCFadeTo actionWithDuration:.5 opacity:165];
id fademax = [CCFadeTo actionWithDuration:.05 opacity:255];
id stallmax = [CCDelayTime actionWithDuration:.05];
id fadeback = [CCFadeTo actionWithDuration:.05 opacity:165];
id stall = [CCDelayTime actionWithDuration:.5];
id fadout = [CCFadeTo actionWithDuration:2.5 opacity:0];
id clean = [CCCallBlock actionWithBlock:^{
    [icn removeFromParentAndCleanup:YES];

}];

CGPoint pos = [self pointLocationOnMapForLocation:theTile.location];
icn.position = ccpAdd(pos, ccp(0, -15));
id enchiladas = [CCSequence actions:fadein, fademax, stallmax, fadeback, stall, fadout, clean, nil];
[icn runAction:enchiladas];
```

EDIT : for a repeating animation (no cleanup then), here is an example from one of my games;

```
CCAction *forever = [CCRepeatForever actionWithAction:[CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:anim]];
```

Comment: YvesLeBorg: I'll have to try this out later but I think I understand what your are suggesting.  One quick question-- when I run the Sequence action, will it run in a loop?  Your code looks like a run-once operation.

Comment: YvesLeBorg: Thank you, again, for your help.  I was looking at this answer, again, as a sample of creating a sequence.  It looks like the code you've added is from a personal project.  Just curious, what are you using that animation sequence for?

Comment: in a RPG i'm developing, some soldiers have passive auras. So when they walk, upon landing on the destination tile, i animate this on each tile where the aura will be effective : it is the icon of the aura skill, that briefly flashes to maximum brightness and fades slowly so that the gamer can see the entire scope of the aura, before making his move (turn based, gamer-cpu-gamer ...)